# Background worker not shown in WPF vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, backgroundworker

Hi all i am new to wpf in vs 2010 .I cannot find it in the toolbox when i select choose item and in .net components it is already checked but it is not there in the controls list.Any idea how to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply create a `BackgroundWorker` instance in the code-behind.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Backgroundworker is not a WPF component, so you won't see it in the toolbox.

You have to create one in code-behind; import `System.ComponentModel`.